# 802.11 Wireless Lan with radio information

Tags: ieee-802.11, wireshark

I just saw in wireshark under "import hexdump" the following types:

- IEEE 802.11 Wireless Lan
- IEEE 802.11 Wireless Lan with radio information

What are exactly is the radio information?

Comment: There are multiple 802.11 frame types. You need to study the 802.11 headers to determine what you are looking at. With an encrypted payload, all you can see is the frame header information. We cannot help you decrypt because that falls under "_bypassing network security or policies_," which is explicitly off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are perfectly explained guides written by Wireshark itself and the community on Wireshark wiki. The information you are looking for can be found on the following links:

https://wiki.wireshark.org/Wi-Fi
https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChIOImportSection.html